# Structure of "get you going on"?

Tags: sentence-structure

What is the structure of the following bolded sentence? And what is the equivalent phrase for it?

> Student: Aha, that's one thing I did know to do. I just copied an
>   article, but I still need three more on my topic from three different
>   journals.
>
> Librarian: **Let's get you going on looking for those then.** We have
>   printed versions of twenty or so psychology journals in the Reference
>   Section. These are the ones published within the last year. Then I
>   think about it... there's a journal named Sleep and Dream.

Comment: A simple "near equivalent" would be *I'll help you look for those [three more articles that you need].* Arguably ***get you going*** implies the librarian only intends to help you ***get started*** (after which she'll leave you to continue the search on your own). But I wouldn't know how to describe the "structure" of the exact cited text in terms that might be helpful to you as a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's get you going on

This means "We will set things up for you to begin." Another way of saying this would be "Let's get started (on)."

> looking for those

This is a gerund, where the verb phrase "looking for those" functions as a noun (an activity).

> [...] then.

The word "then" in this sentence serves as an affirmation. The speaker is acknowledging and supporting the first person's need for more articles.

Alternatively, if the first person had suggested waiting to find the articles, the second speaker might have said "though" to indicate they think it's better to proceed immediately than to wait.

---

So another way of saying this sentence would be "Let me help you start looking for those articles now."